# How can I cancel reverse search without losing text typed?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

When using reverse-search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>) in the `bash` terminal , I can cancel the search using either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>. Both these options will clear the text typed while searching.

However, the most common reason I need to cancel my search is when I realize the command I wanted to type is not in my history, and this often happens only after I've typed a very long command.

Is there some way to cleanly abort the search without losing everything I typed?

Comment: Slightly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358049/cancel-failed-reverse-i-search-in-bash-but-keep-what-i-typed-in

Answer (score 0):

#### Editor: bash

Just mark the command with the mouse, then press *Ctrl+Shift+C*, then *Ctrl+G* and you have it in memory.

#### Editor: tmux

Not sure whether I understand it right. I do not see a problem, and you give the answer yourself. That is how it seems, at least, when taking tmux as the editor. *(not tested, but I guess that Alacritty can do that as well)*

##### Copy

Go into *Ctrl+B+[* mode to be free to roam around in any field of the console. Press *Space* as the starting marker of the "recursive search text". Press *Enter* at the end marker. If you set mouse on in your config, you can also use the mouse to *Shift+mark* and Copy with *Ctrl+Shift+C*, or you can just mark with the mouse and by this, copy to the tmux clipboard.

##### Cancel without losing console text

Then go back to any console text that you had at the start with *Ctrl+g* as you write it as well: anything you had written in the console is still there.

##### Paste

And you now can paste the text of the recursive search on top of that, check middle mouse click, *Ctrl+Shift+V*, or look up other ways.

Answer (score -3):

Try using the cursor movement keys, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: Is this experience based? or just a guess? This doesn't work for me.

Comment: This works for me, using bash version 4.1.2

Comment: My bash reports its version as `4.3.11(1)-release`. Your solution just inserts the command found into the command line and allows me to edit it. OP wants to keep what has been typed, not what has been (approximately) found. Are you sure this is what you get?